# Updating existing records in account object based on conditions in related record

Tags: apex

- I have account object and site object.
- Site object have Supplier__c which is lookup up of account..

If payment__priority__c field in site object is 1 then Payment_priority_group_c field in account object should update to 1.

I am writing script in anonymous code to update the existing records.

```
List <Site__c> siteList = 
   [SELECT
      Id,Payment_Priority__c,Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c, 
      Supplier__r.S360Organization_registered_for_MSME_Act__c,
      Supplier__r.Name 
    FROM Site__c 
    WHERE Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c = null AND
        Supplier__r.Name != NULL LIMIT 100];

List <Site__c> siteListToUpdate = new List <Site__c>();
for(Site__c s : siteList){ 
  if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 99 || s.Payment_Priority__c == Null ) { 
     s.Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c = '10'; 
  }
  else if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 1 ||
          s.Supplier__r.S360Organization_registered_for_MSME_Act__c == 'Yes'){
     s.Supplier__r.Payment_Priority_Group__c = '1'; 
  } 
siteListToUpdate.add(s); }

Update siteListToUpdate;
```

I tried this but still records not getting updated..can u help whats wrong here.

Comment: Couldn't you do it with a formula field? Or does Payment_Priority_Group__c have to be editable?

Answer (score 0):

*I took the liberty of reformatting your code which was posted in an unreadable manner.*

The reason for your error is that a DML statement

```
update siteListToUpdate
```

only will update the `Site__c` object, not its parent Account. SFDC DML statements apply only to the object, not its parents (or children). Parent and children need to be updated explicitly with their own DML statements

Your code needs to look something like this:

```
Set<Account> updatableAccounts = new Set <Account>();
for(Site__c s : siteList){ 
  if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 99 || s.Payment_Priority__c == Null ) { 
    updatableAccounts.add(new Account(Id = s.Supplier__c,
                                      Payment_Priority_Group__c = '10')); 
  }
  else 
  if(s.Payment_Priority__c == 1 ||
      s.Supplier__r.S360Organization_registered_for_MSME_Act__c == 'Yes'){
      updatableAccounts.add(new Account(Id = s.Supplier__c,
                                      Payment_Priority_Group__c = '10')); 
  } 


update updatableAccounts;
```

The use of the Set ensures you are only updating the same Account once since multiple Sites could share a single Account as parent

Comment: No it is not working .getting error like unexpected token <  in List <set> line.

Comment: @VanithaManiVlog It looks like this code was purposefully made so that you couldn't just copy/paste it. Remember, the goal here isn't to do your work for you, it's to help you overcome issues, learn, and grow as a professional. Simply copy/pasting code doesn't lead to much in the way of learning nor growth.